# javascript, how to distribute the elements in list of arrays to a dictionary object

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to build up arrays, EXTRACT elements in list of arrays correspondingly, and then assemble them into a dictionary.

FROM

```
{
    links: [source: "0000", target: "1234", bond: "1111"],
    nodes: [id: "01234", atom: "CHHHH"]
}
```

TO

```
{
    [links: {"source": 0, "target": 1, "bond": 1},
            {"source": 0, "target": 2, "bond": 1},
            {"source": 0, "target": 3, "bond": 1},
            {"source": 0, "target": 4, "bond": 1}],
    [nodes: {"id": 0, "atom": C},
           {"id": 1, "atom": H},
           {"id": 2, "atom": H},
           {"id": 3, "atom": H},
           {"id": 4, "atom": H}]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: The top block is what I generated from for loop, I don't know how to construct the array in the second block.

Comment: please add a valid result. arrays does not have keys in literal notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the objects (suppose it is a valid one) and switch the last index with an array with objects.

```js
var source = { links: { source: "0000", target: "1234", bond: "1111" }, nodes: { id: "01234", atom: "CHHHH" } },
    target = {};

Object.keys(source).forEach(function (k) {
    target[k] = target[k] || [];
    Object.keys(source[k]).forEach(function (l) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < source[k][l].length; i++) {
            target[k][i] = target[k][i] || {};
            target[k][i][l] = source[k][l][i];
            //        ^--------------------^
        }
    });
});

console.log(target);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Cool, I just paste this code, this works perfect for me and it actually works! Thanks you so much! This is my first stackover question. This is a great platform. Many thanks again!